# Find reserved keywords in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, keyword

I am not sure if there is any built-in function in sql server 2008 that will tell whether it is reserved keyword or not.

The reason I wanted to do this is because I find sometimes the column names are using the same name as the reserved keywords, for example, a column called 'desc', 'user', 'state', etc, which then we have to wrap them with square brackets ([desc], [user], [state]) to be able to query the columns correctly.

If such a built-in function does exist, then we probably can do

```
if isReservedKeyword (@name) = true
  set @column = REPLACE(@column, @name, '[' + @name+ ']')
else
  set @column = @name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put brackets around every column. That way you ensure that even reserved words are taken care of.

Comment: this is ok except when dealing with object names that themselves contain brackets - more general/safe solution is `QUOTENAME`

Comment: Don't encourage a practice that puts extra characters around every column every time. Table names will have the same problem. Then all you table and column references EVERYWHERE get wrapped in brackets bloating the code and making harder to read and maintain.

The best choice to to refactor/rename the object such that they do not conflict with reserved words. Failing that, your initial idea to just process your sql code to wrap all the offensive ones seems like a fine temporizing measure. 

In almost all case you can avoid using a reserved word by being more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

Reserved words are documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

That list is exhaustive, but it's not so long that you couldn't just re-enter those into your own database table to check against.

Answer (score 5):

There is a built in function that will take care of this, and also 'unusual' characters: [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)
:

> Returns a Unicode string with the
>   delimiters added to make the input
>   string a valid SQL Server delimited
>   identifier.
>
> The following example takes the
>   character string abc[]def and uses the
>   [ and ] characters to create a valid
>   SQL Server delimited identifier.
>
> `SELECT QUOTENAME('abc[]def')`
>
> Here is the result set.
>
> `[abc[]]def]`
>
> `(1 row(s) affected)`
>
> Notice that the right bracket in the
>   string abc[]def is doubled to indicate
>   an escape character.